# Write the SQL query to generate a list of all students who?

Tags: sql, oracle

[Student1 table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbY8a.png)

I tried to solve it but it always gives me an error

```
select * from student1 where student_fname student_lname like '%a';
select * from student1 where student_fname student_lname like '%a'
                                       *
```

ERROR at line 1:

> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: `where student_lname like '%a%'`  add an ORed condition for the first name.

Comment: If we do your homework for you, How would you learn? Here are a couple of hints: 1. You need to use the wildcard on both sides of the search term. 2. You can do the entire thing in a single query.

Comment: oracle in TeraTerm

Comment: For all those answering the question - keep in mind that the values in `student_fname` and `student_lname` could be mixed case.

Answer (score 5):

Try this? You need to add another % so it looks at both sides of the word to find the character if it is in the middle. Also, use OR so that it doesn't look at only the first or last exclusively.

```
select * 
from student1 
where lower(student_fname) like '%a%' or lower(student_lname) like '%a%'
```

Comment: STUDENT_ID STUDENT_FNAME        STUDENT_LNAME
---------- -------------------- --------------------
     10002 Dave                 Franklin
     10004 Mary                 Gibson   .Still, incomplete last name Anson did not showed up.

Comment: Thanks for the case edit @aMimikyu Hope this works for you now agam

Comment: yeah, it worked.Can you answer this query also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49642409/write-the-sql-query-to-find-students-who-are-enrolled-for-units-offered-in-a-loc

Answer (score 0):

You're close -- you need to separate your conditions with `OR`:

```
select * from student1 where student_fname like '%a%' or student_lname like '%a%';
```

If you want students that have `a` in *both* first and last name, then join your conditions with `AND` instead:

```
select * from student1 where student_fname like '%a%' and student_lname like '%a%';
```

Also note that `'%a'` will give you students that have names *ending* in `a`. Think of the `%` as "matches anything", so `'%a'` means "matches anything, then an a." You want `'%a%'` which is, "matches anything, then an a, then anything."

Comment: SQL> select * from student1 where
  2  student_fname like '%a' and
  3  student_lname like '%a';

no rows selected

Comment: Read my answer again please.

Comment: SQL> select * from student1 where
  2  student_fname like '%a%' or
  3  student_lname like '%a';

STUDENT_ID STUDENT_FNAME        STUDENT_LNAME
---------- -------------------- --------------------
     10002 Dave                 Franklin
     10004 Mary                 Gibson         .

Comment: it still not giving me all names like 10005                      Glory                            Anson

Comment: yeah, it worked.Can you answer this query also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49642409/write-the-sql-query-to-find-students-who-are-enrolled-for-units-offered-in-a-loc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for the cases including letter `a` for both first and last name, you need to use an "and" operator.

```
select * 
from student1 
where student_fname like '%a%' 
and student_lname like '%a%';
```

You can change the keyword `and` into `or` if one of the column is enough for including the letter `a`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from student1 where student_fname like '%a%' or
student_lname like '%a%';
```

`%a%` if you need name-surname 'containing a'

Comment: yeah, it worked.Can you answer this query also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49642409/write-the-sql-query-to-find-students-who-are-enrolled-for-units-offered-in-a-loc

Answer (score 0):

> who have the letter ‘a’ in their name (first name/last name).?

Letter "**a**" could be either **UPPER** or **LOWER**. You need to make your LIKE condition **case-insensitive**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   student1
WHERE  LOWER(student_fname) LIKE '%a%'
OR     LOWER(student_lname) LIKE '%a%';
```

**NOTE** : Using `UPPER`/`LOWER` function on the **regular B-tree indexed-column** will suppress the **index** usage and might be a performance issue. Either create a **function-based index** for UPPER/LOWER, or have separate OR conditions for UPPER/LOWER case:

```
SELECT *
FROM   student1
WHERE  student_fname LIKE '%a%'
OR     student_fname LIKE '%A%'
OR     student_lname LIKE '%a%'
OR     student_lname LIKE '%A%';
```

There are many other ways of doing a case-insensitive operation, you may loook at [**Oracle – Case Insensitive Sorts & Compares**](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/oracle-case-insensitive-sorts-compares/)

Comment: Given that the query is filtering on like `'%a%'` it won't use an index anyway so using `lower()` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: yeah, it worked.Can you answer this query also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49642409/write-the-sql-query-to-find-students-who-are-enrolled-for-units-offered-in-a-loc

Comment: @agam I could, but it looks like you are asking us to do your homework. I recommend you to spend some time reading the documentation and self-learning rather than finding ready made answers. It is for your own good.

Comment: I have my answer in the post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49673239/finding-functional-dependency-of-the-table], I just want to someone to confirm I am on the right path, I found the dependency.Can you check I found all the dependency after that I will do 2nf and 3nf.

Answer (score 0):

Or...

```
SELECT
    first_name,
    last_name
  FROM
    students
 WHERE
    upper(first_name || last_name) LIKE '%A%';
```

Comment: yeah, it worked.Can you answer this query also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49642409/write-the-sql-query-to-find-students-who-are-enrolled-for-units-offered-in-a-loc

Comment: @agam I could but it sounds like you're asking us to do your homework for you

Comment: Not only that but he has not accepted the answer here or in the other question