# Write the SQL query to find students who are enrolled for units offered in a location?

Tags: sql, oracle

[Problem Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9wBP.jpg) "  I think for this all three tables will be used. But I can't establish a relation between table `Student_1` and `Course`.

@ APCThis code is working.But giving only 2 students instead of 3, is there any mistake in my table?.
[Course table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbHHd.jpg) [student_2 table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBIYC.jpg) [Student_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubS3t.jpg) [Answer from @APC code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA2cH.jpg)

Comment: So what happens when you run that statement? Don't say 'doesn't work'. Have a read here: http://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-inner-join/

Comment: select student_id
  2  from student2 join course using(course_id)
  3  where location like '%burwood%';. I tried to run SQL to find a student id instead of student name but that also failed.

Comment: I'm glad you didn't say "didn't work". Instead you said "failed" which is pretty much just as useless. What error did you get? Or did you not get the data you expected? Or did your mouse fall apart?

Comment: for student id one no row selected and for the student name I don't have an idea men

Comment: First get the query right for _two_ tables. `Student1` and `Student2`. Then join in course. Then filter with `where`. Do it in little steps and confirm each step before proceeding. For example your first query should be: `select student_fname,student_lname from student1 join student2 using(student_id);` Did your tutor tell you to use `using`? because that is really non standard and I would recommend against it. Instead I would use `<tabl1> join <table> on`

Comment: ok I will try this code with on.

Comment: Try to make a where filter .but it gave an errorSQL> select `student_fname,student_lname
  2  from student1 join student2 on (student_id)
  3  where year_joined >=2016;
where year_joined >=2016
*
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator`.

Comment: You're mixing up syntax between `on` and `using`. See @APC answer below for correct syntax

Comment: I got it, just want to know how to add more where conditions?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Answer (score 1):

> "for student id one no row selected "

Computers are extremely precise. They will run the code exactly as you write it. Your query has this WHERE clause:

```
location like '%burwood%'
```

But if you look carefully at the data in `course` you will spot that the value in `location` is `Burwood`. `'Burwood'` does not equal `'burwood'` because of that difference in the case of the leading letter.

You would have gotten results if you had written your WHERE clause like this:

```
location like '%urwood%'
```

However it is always better to filter with an equality filter:

```
 select s1.student_id
        , s1.student_fname
        , s1.student_fname
        , c.course
 from course c
      join student2 s2 on s2.course_id = c.course_id
      join student1 s1 on s1.student_id = s2.student_id
 where c.location = 'Burwood';
```

Comment: This query already returns the student name. What problem are you having?

Comment: sorry there is some error.It is giving only two student id .select `student_id
  2  from student2 join course using(course_id)
  3  where location = 'Burwood';

STUDENT_ID
----------
     10004
     10002`

Comment: @APC code working but giving only two students.Please see post for ss

Comment: Probably it's your data. My guess is you have a trailing space on one of the  entries of `location`. Unfortunately your persistence in using screenshots makes it hard to see what's going on and impossible to diagnose it. If you want us to help you you need to post a reproducible test case, which means cut'n'pasting the actual text from your SQL/*Plus session.

Comment: Sorry, got it solved, an error in my data.One more query how to solve if to show only students who have enrolled in ‘Database’ course or a course that has been offered in Burwood.By adding a or where statement?

Comment: Yes, you would add an OR clause to the WHERE statement. If you have found this answer helpful you should consider upcoming and/or accepting it. Accepted answers improve the quality of StackOverflow for other Seekers.

Comment: Thanks, men for all the help.But I have still some problems understanding your answer, something I am not familiar with like.`select **s1**.student_id
        , **s1**.student_fname
        , s1.student_fname
        , c.course
 from course c
      join student2 **s2** on **s2**.course_id = c.course_id
      join student1 s1 on s1.student_id = s2.student_id
 where c.location = 'Burwood';` Like use of s1 and s2

Comment: Those are table aliases. It is a shorter way of referencing the table, which we need to do when working with multiple tables which have columns with the same name (STUDENT_ID, COURSE_ID).

Comment: Thanks, men and that OR condition with database course worked.

Comment: @agam, given that you're problem has been more than solved, now the right thing to do is accept this as the answer.

Comment: done sorry men I am new to this forum did not know about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select     
st1.student_id,st1.student_lname,st1.student_fname,c.course
from student1 st1
left join student2 st2 on st1.student_id=st2.student_id
left join course c on st2.course_id=c.course_id
where upper(c.location) like 'BURWOOD'
```

Comment: write Burwood in place of BORWOOD. Or change where clause like this  Where upper(c.location) like 'BURWOOD'

Comment: @APC code working but giving only two students.Please see post for ss

Comment: Change course_id in your Student2 table from SIT772 to SIT722

Comment: Change and try my select. It will return 4 students

Comment: what you want me to change?

Comment: You dont have course with SIT772 id in your course table. But in student2 table in course_id column you have SIT772. This course doesnt exist in course table. May be this id should be SIT722. This is id of course with location Burwood in course table.

Comment: i fixed that thing.

Comment: does my answer give you result which you expected ?(after changing table data)

Comment: no your answer still giving 0 rows.But @APC code worked fine.Give me 4 students.

Comment: I think it should work. copy again from here and try. I dont now why gives 0 result

Comment: no worries.Can ask you question? like st1.student_id,st1.student_lname,st1.student_fname,c.course
from student1 st1
left join student2 st2 on st1.student_id=st2.student_id
left join course c on st2.course_id=c.course_id
where upper(c.location) like 'BURWOOD'.What is the concept of this st2 ,st1 &c.I am not familer with this concept.

Comment: This called alias. I give alias for table name inside query. because i dont want write table names when i select columns, alias is shorter. for examle st1 is shorter than student1. You also can give alias names for column names.

Comment: select st1.student_id  s1_id from Student1 st1   or  Select st1.student_id as s1_id from student1 st1. Here s1_id is alias for column student_id. but you cant use column aliases in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
select s1.student_id
        , s1.student_fname
        , s1.student_lname
        , c.course
 from course c
      join student2 s2 on s2.course_id = c.course_id
      join student1 s1 on s1.student_id = s2.student_id
 where c.location = 'Burwood';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select Student_ID,Student_FName,c.Location from Student1 as s1 Left Join Student2 as s2 on s1.Student_ID = s2.Student_ID Left join Course as c on s2.Course_ID = c.Course_ID where c.Location = "Burwood";
```

> this MS SQL QUERY YOU CAN TRY IT

Comment: The question is tagged `[oracle]` so it needs Oracle syntax. The `[sql]` tag just refers to the SQL language and not MS SQL Server.

Comment: i just give the some reference that's not s oracle